# Keepalived: Interface queue is empty

Tags: 14.04, networking, server

I installed keepalived on two Linux Server (Ubuntu 14.04)
 Konifg File:

```
! ConfigFile for keepalived
global_defs{
vrrp_instance VI_1 {
        state MASTER
        interface eth0
        virtual_router_id 51
        priority 110
        advert_int 1
}
virtual_ipaddress {
        192.168.178.16
}
}
```

The two server can communicate with each other but in the syslog stands, that the Interface queue is empty:

```
Jan  5 13:54:06 Linux01 Keepalived_healthcheckers[1016]: Interface queue is empty
    Jan  5 13:54:06 Linux01 Keepalived_healthcheckers[1016]: Registering Kernel netl
    ink reflector
    Jan  5 13:54:06 Linux01 Keepalived_healthcheckers[1016]: Registering Kernel netl
    ink command channel
    Jan  5 13:54:06 Linux01 Keepalived_vrrp[1017]: Opening file '/etc/keepalived/kee
    palived.conf'.
    Jan  5 13:54:06 Linux01 Keepalived_vrrp[1017]: Configuration is using : 57962 By
    tes
    Jan  5 13:54:06 Linux01 Keepalived_vrrp[1017]: Using LinkWatch kernel netlink re
    flector...
    Jan  5 13:54:06 Linux01 Keepalived_healthcheckers[1016]: Opening file '/etc/keep
    alived/keepalived.conf'.
    Jan  5 13:54:06 Linux01 Keepalived_healthcheckers[1016]: Configuration is using
    : 4421 Bytes
    Jan  5 13:54:06 Linux01 Keepalived_healthcheckers[1016]: Using LinkWatch kernel
    netlink reflector...
    Jan  5 13:54:07 Linux01 Keepalived_vrrp[1017]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Transition to
     MASTER STATE
```

I can't ping to the virtual IP.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem:

I had an error in my syntax. The global_defs shouldn't go over the other configuration. The  virtual_ipaddress{} should be in the vrrp_instance config tag.